# Dealing with multi-parameter assignment and rails 3.2 key-value store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using the build-in key-value store for the first time now in a model called `Applicant`.

(I want to save the applicant objects serialized because its being send to an external application later and its just saved as a local backup.)

The applicant model has a "birthday" attribute.

```
store :data, accessors: [ ..., :birthday ]
```

The form helper for date fields splits the attribute into multiple fields for day/month/year.

Normally when assigning the params, ActiveRecord automatically puts them together again.

But when using the key-value store, this is not the fact and I get an exception raised:

```
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors Exception: 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes
```

I could put the birthday(1i) birthday(2i) birthday(3i) params together in the controller, but this is not really what I want to do. Is there a better approach?

Thanks